# Can't check-in ASP .Net 5 project because it misses global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm not being able to check-in a newly created ASP.NET 5 application on TFS (Team Foundation Server). Every time I try to check-in the project, it fails and gives me the following error: "Could not find file 'Global.asax'.". I know that ASP.NET 5 is not yet completely released, but can anyone at least tell me why this happens and if there's a fix or will be?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Edit the cs.proj file in notepad and remove the Global.asax entry.

Comment: That's the thing, there is no global.asax on csproj and yet the tfs requires it...

Comment: That sure sounds like a bug. How about just adding one to the project, but leave it with all the empty event handlers.  In all my projects I always use a Global.asax if for nothing else to handle "un-handled" exceptions in a consistent manner.

Answer (score 0):

To remove it from the `csproj` instead of the "notepad solution" you can also choose to `unload` the [project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt479x1t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) from Visual Studio and edit it, before `load` it again.

Comment: That's the thing, there is no global.asax on csproj and yet the tfs requires it..

Answer (score 0):

I have a work around that did the job for me:

- Exclude all the *"ghost"* files from the changes
- Check-in the project
- Undo the *"ghost"* files